# If each prime divides $a$, then the product of primes divides $a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If $p_1, p_2,...,p_k$ are distinct primes and each $p_i \mid a$ , $i=1, 2,...,k$ does this implies that $p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdots p_k \mid a$?

Comment: Yes (consider the prime factorization of $a$)

Comment: I guess you want them to be distinct?

Comment: $$p_1|a \to a=p_1.q_1\\
(p_1,p2)=1 ,p_2|a \to a=p_1.p_2.q_2\\\vdots$$

Comment: As per the current statement, consider $p_1=2,\,p_2=2,\,p_3=2,\,p_4=2,\,a=2$.

Comment: @Khosrotash I dont understand.

Comment: @Sassatelli  and Felix 6 its distinct primes :) sorry I forgot to mention

Comment: Also, i guess you want the primes to be in N={1,2,3,4,...}?

Comment: Sorry for the errors guys. Ive edited it already

Comment: Since if we are somwhere where the prime factorization isn't unique  this mustn't be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unless the primes are not all distinct. 
say for example $p_1 = 3, p_2 = 3, p_3 = 3, a = 3$, **the product 27 for certain does not divide three**

But if they are distinct, then the product would divide since every natural number except one has only **one unique prime factorisation.**

Comment: And if we are somewhere without an unique prime factorization (f.ex. {a+b\sqrt(-5); a, b \in \Z} the statement does not have to be true.